# COM component not activated due to privilege issue

Tags: com, permissions, ms-word, office-addins

We have developed an office add-in. Its working fine with every other system except one. In that particular system when we try to load the app, it fails with a generic error (*This app could not be started. Close this dialog to ignore the problem or click "Restart" to try again.*). Event viewer has the following details

*The machine-default permission settings do not grant Local Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID 
{9BA05972-F6A8-11CF-A442-00A0C90A8F39}
and APPID 
{9BA05972-F6A8-11CF-A442-00A0C90A8F39}
to the user STC\inmchandr SID (S-1-5-21-2779513660-4158667818-3257731910-104078) from address LocalHost (Using LRPC) running in the application container Unavailable SID (Unavailable). This security permission can be modified using the Component Services administrative tool.*

The specified CLSID points to ShellWindows component, which is running with "Interactive User" account. I am unable to change the other security permissions like launching permissions for that component in DCom config. I tried to change the permission for the corresponding registry entry (as suggested in [this link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/3313c6c5-383a-4051-a22a-04452f87642a/the-machinedefault-permission-settings-do-not-grant?forum=sharepointsearch)) But, nothing worked out.

The winword.exe is running as the same user who logged in. This system and the other systems (where it is working) are in the same network and I tried running gpupdate as well.

(In that problematic system) The same app is loading when we tried to run Word as administrator. The URL used for that taskpane app is launching without any issues from browsers

OS: Windows 8.1
Processor: 64 bit
Office: 2013

Could anyone help us out to resolve the issue?